# How to add to a linked list within a separate chaining hash table in C

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, symbol-table

Here are the relevant structs for my question.

```
//A SymEntry is the building block for linked lists of (name, attribute) pairs
typedef struct SymEntry {
  char * name;
  void * attribute;
  struct SymEntry * next;
} SymEntry;

/*
Each symbol table is represented by a SymTab
size is the current number of lists in the separate chaining hash table
contents is an array of lists (i.e. points to the zeroth element in the array)
if current is not NULL it points to the current (name, attribute) pair in the symbol table
*/
  typedef struct {
    int size;
    SymEntry ** contents;
    SymEntry *current;
  } SymTab;
```

I have a project to create a Symbol Table in c. We are to implement a separate chaining hash table to accomplish this. I believe that I created the initial, empty hash table correctly. Below is my implementation of that.

```
SymTab * createSymTab(int size) {
  int i;  
  SymTab *symbolTable = malloc(sizeof(SymTab));
  symbolTable->contents = (SymEntry**)malloc(size * sizeof(SymEntry));
  symbolTable->current = (SymEntry*)malloc(sizeof(SymEntry));
  symbolTable->size = size;

  for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
    SymEntry *newEntry = malloc(sizeof(SymEntry));
    newEntry -> name = NULL;
    newEntry -> attribute = NULL;
    newEntry -> next = NULL;
    
    symbolTable->contents[i] = newEntry;
    
  }
  symbolTable->current = NULL;
  return symbolTable;
}
```

I seem to also have it working to where it can add the first node (SymEntry) in the linked list. Below is my code to add an entry, along with my hash method.

```
int enterName(SymTab * table, char *name) {
  if (findName(table, name) == 0) {
    int size = table->size;
    int hashNum = hash(name, &size);
    SymEntry *head = table->contents[hashNum];
    printf("Hash Number is %d\n", hashNum);
    if (head->name == NULL) {
      printf("Head is null\n");
      head->name = name;
      head->attribute = NULL;
    }
    else {
      printf("Head is not null\n");
      SymEntry *newNode = malloc(sizeof(SymEntry));
      newNode->name = name;
      newNode->attribute = NULL;
      newNode->next = head;
      head = newNode;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int hash(char *key, int * size) {
  int hash = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int sizeOfNum = *size;
  printf("Key Value: %s   Size of Number: %d\n", key, sizeOfNum);
  
  while (key && key[i]) {
    hash = (hash + key[i] % sizeOfNum);
    i++;
    }
  
  return hash % sizeOfNum;
}
```

Lastly, the below code is what I am using to test things out. If my understanding of everything is correct, the name that should be printing is Jess, my second entry, but instead I am only seeing Wes. Both of these names hash out to the same number, which in this case would be 5. What exactly am I doing wrong when I go to add a node (SymEntry) to the list? My output recognizes that the head is not empty when I go to add Jess, so I know the first entry works.

```
int main(void) {
  SymTab * symbolTable = createSymTab(6);
  enterName(symbolTable, "wes");
  enterName(symbolTable, "jess");
  SymEntry * example = symbolTable->contents[5];
  printf("%s\n", example->name);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `head = newNode;`. That doesn't do what you need. `head` is just a local variable so that statement does not link the `newNode` into the hash table. If you examing `table->contents[hashNum]` you will see it is always the same value no matter how many nodes you add. In addition, would suggest you restructure the code to initalise `table->contents[hashNum]` to NULL instead of to a node that has an empty `name` field.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Helped me understand and solve the issue.